# rotate(-90deg) not work IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem ... that CSS does not work in IE8 ...

> -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
>       -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
>       -moz-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
>       -moz-transform-origin: right top;
>       -o-transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
>       -o-transform-origin: right top;
>       transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg);
>   transform-origin: right top;

I've tried this with css

> -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)"

but did not work

Comment: Correct. It doesn't work in IE8. Is there anything else we can help with?

Comment: Did you search the internet on this one? The transform rule does not apply to IE8. You need to find a workaround. You could try this http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, IE8 does not support CSS3, which includes `transform`, etc.. You should either upgrade your browser (to at least IE9), or switch to another, more modern one, like Chrome or Firefox. Alternatively, you can use a polyfill.